# Regular Expression to find “lastname firstname”

Tags: regex, grep

We have a file that contain only lastname with space and firstname.

The file looks like this:

```
Alex Roni
ToMmy Rid
Christian Olav
JohHn PeTter
Flara Sbastian
Hovard Kai
Runne Nervin
OlaAf RoOni
Olaf Roni
```

We want to grep this file in 4 ways.

First we want it's to find any lastname lastname starts with either N, O, P, Q, R.

I write the following code:

```
(^[N-R])
```

2nd find first and last names are both exactly 4 letters long.

I write the following code. But seem doesn't work. It must grep `Olaf Roni`

```
(^[N-R]{4}+)([N-R]{4}+)
```

3rd first and lastnames do not contain an `s`. Is that correct, working as well.

```
^[^s]*$
```

4rd find lastname contains two big characters as in `MacDonald`. The 2nd big characters can occur anywhere in the name.

This code doesn't work as well.

```
^(.*?[A-Z]{2,}.*)+(.*?[A-Z]{2,}.*)$
```

Comment: `[N-R]{4}+` doesn't do what you think it does. Looks like you should start by reading a regex tutorial.

Comment: You have right, return null.

Comment: Homework, by any chance?

Comment: I hope you never have a "José Manuel de las Heras" or something similar ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lookahead:

```
^(?=\w{4}\s\w{4}$)[N-R].*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bM2vD1/2)

---

The regex of /[N-R]/ matches only one character in the range of N, O, P, Q, R. If you use [N-R]{4} you are saying you want to match 4 characters in the same range, such as `NNNN` would be a match.

For a name as you describe, you would want:

```
[N-R][a-zA-Z]{3}

 ^^^              One letter in the range N-R
       ^^^        an ASCII letter
              ^^  proceeding match 3 times
```

So two names that fit that pattern separated by a space would be:

```
^[N-R][a-zA-Z]{3} [N-R][a-zA-Z]{3}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bM2vD1/3)

Then you can add additional lookaheads for the other constraints you described. There is a great piece on regex lookaheads at RexEgg [HERE.](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: Great. You can add other conditions with more lookaheads. If it is working, please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: this code `(^[N-R])` greps any lastname that start between N and R, but how we can do the same jobb for only firstname too that sart between N and R.

Comment: You can use something like `^[N-R]\w{3}\s[N-R]\w{3}$` or `^(?=[N-R]\w{3}\s[N-R]\w{3}$).*` with a lookahead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

`.* (.*[A-Z].*[A-Z].*)`

http://rubular.com/r/wuWMKFJlir

Answer (score 0):

Following is expression

^(([N-R][\w]{3}(\s?)){2})$

Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/wM2oE4/9